# Add block after 3rd list item in a yii2 listview widget

Tags: yii2

I have not worked with the listview widget before so I cant find a solution for this, as I output a list with items I wanted to do 2 things, 1. auto increment and unique ID/number to each list item, 2. add a block(custom piece of code) after each 3rd list item.

I could not find any documentation about this so not sure if this is possible.

```
echo ListView::widget([
    'id' => 'listofitems',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
]);


<div id="listofitems">
   <div class="list_item_wrapper">

       // my items which are in a seperate file
       <div class="list_item_wrapper">
       // when using the $index to check for a certain number the code will be build here.
       </div>

   </div>

   // the needed solution
   if($index == 12 || $index == 12){
      echo 'some div here';
   }
</div>
```

Comment: Did you configured `itemView` property?

Comment: hey i updated the answer hope it includes what you are trying to achieve, see the **Edit** part.

Comment: see **Update 2** in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `itemView` option for the `ListView` widget where you can either provide

- Specify as a callback `function ($model , $key , $index , $widget) {` and add your custom HTML inside and do your custom operations like check every third item,or use the actual `id` by calling `$model->id` and appending it with the html tag attribute, it provides you

  - `$model`: mixed, the data model
  - `$key`: mixed, the key value associated with the data item
  - `$index`: integer, the zero-based index of the data item in the items array returned by $dataProvider.
  - `$widget`: ListView, this widget instance

  For example

  ```
  echo ListView::widget([
      'id' => 'listofitems',
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'itemView'=>function ($model , $key , $index , $widget) {
            //Do your Thing with Html you want to draw
            //return '<div></div>';
       }
  ]);
  ```
- Or provide the view file path to the option, you can still use the above given params in the view file

  For Example

  ```
   echo ListView::widget([
              'id' => 'listofitems',
              'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
              'itemView'=>'_view-name'
    ]);
  ```

  Your view can look like

  ```
  <?php
  use yii\helpers\Html;
  ?>
  <div class="card">
      <div class="header">
          <h3 class="title"><?= Html::encode ( $model->title ) ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="body"><img src="<?= Html::encode ( $model->name ) ?>"><?= Html::encode ( $model->id ) ?></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
  ```

### UPDATE

If your requirements are to draw or add an element after every item or any number of items you can use the [`afterItem`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview#$afterItem-detail) option which takes an anonymous function that is called once `AFTER` rendering each data model, it passes same set of parameters as [`beforeItem`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview#$beforeItem-detail)

- `$model`: the current data model being rendered
- `$key`: the key value associated with the current data model
- `$index`: the zero-based index of the data model in the model array returned by $dataProvider
- `$widget`: the ListView object

### `UPDATE2`

The below should work in your case with the given HTML

```
<div id="listofitems">
    <?php
    echo ListView::widget ( [
        'id' => 'listofitems' ,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider ,
        'afterItem=' > function($model , $key , $index , $widget) {
            // the needed solution
            if ( $index == 12 || $index == 12 ) {
                return 'some div here';
            }
        } ,
        'itemView' => function ($model , $key , $index , $widget) {
            //Do your Thing with Html you want to draw
            return '<div class="list_item_wrapper">

                // my items which are in a seperate file
                <div class="list_item_wrapper">
                // when using the $index to check for a certain number the code will be build here.
                </div>

            </div>
         ';
        }
    ] );
    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use the index var im still inside the item, so working with a grid is not going to work now, I need to add a element outside the items.

Comment: can yo uadd the exact HTML only that you like to achieve with the `ListView` as i couldnot get what you are trying to say

Comment: Atm the items are wrapped in a outher div, which prevents me from adding a custom div,the idea is to add a custom element after each 6 items, but when i use the $index var inside the items render it will show this element inside the item wrap element.

Comment: I have provided an example of my issue.

Comment: Thanks this will solve my issue, I used and echo instead of an return, thats why it didnt work how stupid of me haha. Many thanks!!!!

Comment: lol you are welcome @user759235 , i was thinking why it wasnt working in your case

Comment: is there an way to count the total number of displayed items?

Comment: The `$index` holds the last item number added starting from 0 @user759235

Answer (score 1):

There is such an index by default in the widget. Configure the 'itemView' attribute of the ListView widget, that means you can use a custom view which will be rendered for each item. Like this:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'id' => 'listofitems',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '/site/item',
?>
```

in your view file `/site/item.php`, you can access the index of the current item:

```
<?php 
    var_dump($index);
?>
```

[More info about the `itemView` property  here.](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview#$itemView-detail)